# Vue + Vuetify transition-group list animation issue when removing last item

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs-transition

I am trying to get `transition-group` to work with my layout. It mostly works, except when removing the last item in a long list with a scroll bar.
When I remove the last item, the space it occupied does not shrink gracefully, it waits until the transition completes and then collapses suddenly. I am trying to get it to animate smoothly.

I set up a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6c2vx0ws/) which reproduces the same issue. I discovered that if I increase the layout margin to `<v-layout ma-5>` for example, the problem goes away. But this is not a solution for me as I need it to work regardless of the presence of margin.